# Inverting, single-supply comparator not working as expected

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, oscilloscope, comparator

I am trying to convert an input sine wave to a square wave. The sine wave is centered at 2.5V and has an amplitude of 2V, with a frequency of 100kHz.

I am looking for a hysteresis of 100mV centered around 2.5V. (ie. 50mV below and 50mV above 2.5V)

I am trying to achieve something like the following (except that the output is inverted), where both waves are centered about 2.5V:

[image]

To do so I looked through [Design with Operational Amplifiers and Analog ICs](http://online.sfsu.edu/sfranco/BookOpamp/OpampsJacket.pdf), and I thought that I could work with a VTC offsetting single-supply inverting Schmitt trigger.

[image]

I then calculated the resistance values according to my parameters.

```
VTH = 2.55V
VTL = 2.45V
VCC = 5V
```

[image]

Assuming `R3 = 100kΩ` and `R4 = 2.2kΩ`, I calculated `R1` and `R2` both being 4.1kΩ`.

I proceeded to construct the circuitry on Proteus software using the [LM311](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm311.pdf) comparator.

[image]

And here is my output.

[image]

Yellow is Channel A, Blue is Channel B.
I zoomed in on the square wave can be seen from the dials.

[image]

The output is not only attenuated, but also unevenly centered. The book mentions none of these effects, so I suspect that I am missing something more fundamental here. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: You have both scope channels set for AC coupling - that will remove any DC component from the signal, so you won't know where the signal is relative to Ground.  The two vertical position sliders have different non-zero settings which will also change the vertical position of the traces.

Comment: Also you have not said what the input signal level is not have you said whether it is adequately biased at 2.5 volts.

Comment: Thanks, updated images of oscilloscope. @Andyaka, input signal level is adequately biased at 2.5V, with an amplitude of 2V.

Comment: LM311 has enormous gain, and large output-stage current surges during transitions. You may have oscillations. Use a Ground plane. Use a very small package, so inductance in the VDD and GND pins are minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tied the collector of the NPN output to ground and you are trying to take an output from the emitter - you have this the wrong way round. Tie emitter to ground and use a pull-up on the collector like most folk (who still use this ancient part): -

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. This very strangely yields no output on my oscilloscope. I will try other comparators such as the LM397.

Comment: I must be using the wrong simulator. Got an output 10 minutes after I started the simulation, which has never happened before. This was it. When connecting the output to pin 1 I immediately got an incorrect output, but when connected to pin, I got an output waveform appearing after 10 minutes. Thanks

Comment: Ten minutes is an awfully long time to wait for an output!